# publication of VB.net project on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing this post because my app doesn't work on other computers but works on mine as well as another developer's computer.

I published the installation on a server, users download and then launch the application but when they enter their login and password, it shows that the login credentials are bad even though I'm sure they are good since I have looked in the database.

And I repeat myself but the application only works well on another developer's pc.

I have no idea where this can come from so if you have any ideas I'm interested.

Here is the code to authenticate

```
'Paramêtres de connexion à la DB
Private ReadOnly strConn As String = "Server=" & My.Settings.nomServeur & "; DataBase= " & My.Settings.nomBDD & "; Uid=" & My.Settings.idUser & "; Pwd=" & My.Settings.mdp & "; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Private Sub BtnConnexion_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConnexion.Click
    'Si le login ou le mot de passe est vide alors afficher un message d'erreur
    If tbLogin.Text = Nothing Or tbMdp.Text = Nothing Then
        'Affichage d'un message d'erreur
        ErrorMessage("Merci de remplir tous les champs")
        'Quitte la fonction
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'Création d'une requête sql qui récupère les données de l'utilisateur grâce à son login et mot de passe
        strSql = "select * from utilisateur where login = '" & tbLogin.Text & "' and mdp = '" & tbMdp.Text & "'"

        'Initialisation de variables
        Dim user, compta, directeur, admin As String
        user = ""
        compta = ""
        directeur = ""
        admin = ""

        Try
            'Création de la connexion
            ObjetConnection = New SqlConnection(strConn)
            'Création de la commande
            ObjetCommand = ObjetConnection.CreateCommand()
            'Affectation de la requête sql dans la commande
            ObjetCommand.CommandText = strSql
            'Ouverture de la connexion
            ObjetConnection.Open()

            'permet de récupérer les résultats d'une requete sql qui contient Count, avg, max, min, sum
            Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
            'Exécution de la requête
            myReader = ObjetCommand.ExecuteReader()

            'Lecture de toutes les lignes du résultat de la requête
            Do While myReader.Read()
                'Récupération des données de la ligne du résultat de la requête
                user = myReader.GetValue(7).ToString()
                compta = myReader.GetValue(8).ToString()
                directeur = myReader.GetValue(9).ToString()
                admin = myReader.GetValue(10).ToString()
            Loop

            'Si l'admin est à 1 alors l'utilisateur est un admin et affiché la page de gestion des modules
            If Int(admin) = 1 Then
                'Affichage de la page de gestion des modules
                GestionModules.Show()
                'Rend invisible la page actuelle (Authentification)
                Me.Visible = False
            End If
            'Si l'utilisateur est à 1 et tous les autres rôles sont à 0 alors
            If user = 1 And admin = 0 And compta = 0 And directeur = 0 Then
                'Affichage de la page de création de l'entete
                CreationEntete.Show()
                'Rend invisible la page actuelle (Authentification)
                Me.Visible = False
            End If
            'Si la compta est à 1 et l'admin est à 0 alors l'utilisateur fait parti de la compta
            If compta = 1 And admin = 0 And directeur = 0 Then
                'Affichage de la page de gestion des modules
                GestionModules.Show()
                'Rend invisible la page actuelle (Authentification)
                Me.Visible = False
            End If
            'Si le directeur est à 1 et l'admin est à 0 alors l'utilisateur est le directeur
            If directeur = 1 And admin = 0 And compta = 0 Then
                'Affichage de la page de gestion des modules
                GestionModules.Show()
                'Rend invisible la page actuelle (Authentification)
                Me.Visible = False
            End If

            'Fermeture de la connexion
            ObjetConnection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Affichage d'un message d'erreur
            ErrorMessage("Erreur le mot de passe ou login est incorrect")
        End Try

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, let me say that commenting every line is bad because it makes code harder to read. Writing a comment to say that you are creating a database connection is totally pointless. Who do you think is going to read that code who doesn't understand what creating a connection looks like? The same for most of those other comments. The point of comments should be to provide information that you can't get from the code alone, like WHY you are doing something. You only need to explain WHAT you're doing if the code is poorly written.

Comment: As for the issue, if the code fails to find a matching record with the query then it's because there's no matching record. The fact that you're sure that there is a matching record doesn't change that. How about getting all the records and looping through them to see if you can find a match in your VB code. If you can't then you can display the records and use you eyes to see why there's no match.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, for the problem how is it done in this case that the page is displayed correctly on my pc and on that of my colleague?

Comment: The only possible conclusion is that there is something different about the databases. That's assuming that the inputs actually are what you think they are. If it were me, I'd add copious amounts of logging to the code and get a full trace of everything that's happening and then compare the difference machines.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're connecting to the correct instance of the db?  One thing i note, when performing the authentication process, your reporting incorrect credentials regardless of the error encountered.  Maybe change your message box to show ex.ToString().  It may give you some more useful information

Comment: Thanks Hursey, i displayed ex.ToString correctly and I think I encountered an error, it must come from the rights to connect to the database. I am trying to find out why it does not take the connection parameters that I assign to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found, the problem was with the connection line.
Here is the new connection.

```
Public strConn As String = "Data Source=" + My.Settings.nomServeur + ";Initial Catalog=" + My.Settings.nomBDD + ";User ID=" + My.Settings.idUser + ";Password=" + My.Settings.mdp + ""
```